# What is the difference between the function of MongoGridFS::put and MongoGridFS::storeFile in php?

Tags: php, mongodb

I was puzzled with that what is the difference between MongoGridFS::put and MongoGridFS::storeFile except the parameter of options in php?

```
public mixed MongoGridFS::storeFile ( string $filename [, array $extra = array() [, array $options = array() ]] )

public mixed MongoGridFS::put ( string $filename [, array $extra = array() ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right - no differences except $options array. But setting 'safe' option Mongo can throw MongoCursorException and if save fails and you can catch it.